# Laravel redirect to intended page after login/register

Tags: laravel

I am new to Laravel. I am using Laravel's auth controllers for login/register on my website. After login/register, it will redirect to a dashboard. This is fine.

The problem is when the user (not logged in) submits a particular form. The form submission will take the user to a protected page. The auth system will intercept this (if not logged in) and ask for the user to login and the user can sign in. But after the sign in it won't get redirected to the actual destination. Instead, it goes back to the previous page. I tried the `redirectto->intended()` way in the middleware. It still does not work.

Comment: AFAIK this should work out of the box, no?  It must be something to do with your form submission method, or how the Auth protection is applied there.  Edit your question, show the bare minimum of code to reproduce the problem.  It is great you set up a workaround, but I'd definitely try to get the built-in solution handling this if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. Use HTTP session. I am not sure if this is the best method.

1. `POST` the form to a route which doesn't need authentication
2. Validate and store the form data in the session using the controller
3. Redirect to the protected route where the auth will intercept and ask the user to login
4. After successful login, redirect to the original destination page using `return redirect()->intended('defaultPage');`
5. Access the form data from session inside the blade view

I am not storing any sensitive data in session. I have no idea how secure this method is.
If you have any suggestions please post.